# Record Audio and Upload as Wav or MP3 to server

Tags: flash, audio, mp3, record

Im not sure if Im asking the right place, but basically Im looking for advice on the best way to:

Record Audio through a microphone on a website and Upload the audio as a Wav or MP3 file to the server

Has anyone got extensive experience with flash, would this be difficult to do, is there anything on the market that currently does this?

I was thinking about implimenting this as a Java applet but I find java applets abit annoying to use, abit 1998! Are there any tools that do this already or anyone got any guides or whatever

Any advice is appreciated

Thanks
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Adobe Flash Media Server (http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/) or Java servers with support of incoming sound streams.

With FMS it is realy simple. You create in flash swf-app that reads microphone and send sound stream to server. FMS will write it as .flv automatically. You should find few samples answering yours problem in Adobe documentation.

Comment: Flash Player can not encode raw mic sound as mp3 and thus FMS will never write to mp3. Flash Player can encode mic sound using Speex or NellyMoser's ASAO and the FMS will write this audio data to a .flv file.

Comment: http://audior.ec records straight to mp3 and saves to your web server directly without Flash Media Server.

Answer (score 1):

This flash program does this, record, convert to mp3, and upload to your server:

http://fms.denniehoopingarner.com/barebonesRecorder/

If is not free, and can be licensed for $99, but if someone could provide the source code of a similar thing, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth having a look at Processing, if you are not familiar with it you can write java applet, without alot of the hassle.
There is also great documentation, and active forums.

http://processing.org/learning/libraries/recordlinein.html

Otherwise you could use listenup [ Price: $200 ]

http://www.filesland.com/companies/Mobileer-Inc/ListenUp.html

Hope this helps,

.k

Answer (score 0):

you can also record with [MP3 Recorder Studio](http://www.maniactools.com/soft/mp3-recorder/index.shtml), save file to mp3 and then upload to the server
as an option though

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [FLVAR](http://flvar.com/) which is a Flash based audio recorder that runs in the browser.

As mentioned by Konrad, It uses a media server like Wowza, FMIS or [Red5](http://code.google.com/p/red5/).

It supports the **2 audio codecs** present in Flash Player for **encoding**: Nelly Moser ASAO and Speex.

You can use ffmpeg and FLVAR's APIs to convert the resulting .flv file to .mp3.