# Javascript alternative to JavaSonics ListenUp

Tags: javascript, java, audio, audio-recording

I'm working on a server that has been using [JavaSonics ListenUp](http://www.javasonics.com/) (written in Java) to record audio via browser at clients and upload it to the server.

The problem is: the software was discontinued, no longer updated or supported, and, because it's Java, it doesn't run on every web browser, as Google Chrome/Chromium and Microsoft Edge, for example, don't support NPAPI plugins (like Java) anymore.

I wanted to know what can I use for the same job (record audio, upload audio files, play audio) to put it on the website I'm working on. Alternatives on Javascript would be awesome!

PS. There's a [topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261743/record-audio-and-upload-as-wav-or-mp3-to-server/) where people talk about flash tools, but I'd rather not use them. Plus, I guess people who used that JavaSonics software might want an alternative also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use HTML5: [getUSerMedia()](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

Comment: Please give more details. Sharing just links is not a good practice. Links can become invalid with some time. You can keep the link, but please paste the relevant information from it here on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out recorder.js.
https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

It's a javascript library that lets users record audio. After recording, you can export the audio to a WAV file, or upload the BLOB to your server, or whatever.